# Fancybox Ajax Class hide

Tags: ajax, replace, fancybox

Hey i use Fancybox Ajax to load some content form another website.

like this:

```
<a href="{url controller=custom sCustom=28}" class="fancybox fancybox.ajax" title="Payment / Dispatch">Payment / Dispatch</a></br>
```

So no the page gets loaded via ajax if i click on it.

some ugly class apears from the other page.

so i want to hack into fancy box or some other method to hide the class modal_close from been displayed. after fancybox loads the content and renders it to the fancybox popup.

Comment: <a href="#" class="modal_close" title="#LoginActionClose#"> is in the loaded content. i want to hide.